# Character merge

Tags: symbols, characters, semantics

Is there any way to merge two characters in LaTeX? For example, I would like to combine the two symbols `\#` and `1` to get

> #1

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a bit unclear: `\#1` will do, or I am missing something?

Comment: I thought he read it as a command. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command names are of two types:

- control sequences
- control symbols

The former type are commands whose name consists of all *letters* (a–z A–Z);<sup>1</sup> the name can be formed by any number of letter. Spaces after the command name are ignored. Also any nonletter will interrupt the scanning of the name.

Thus `\LaTeX2` or `\LaTeX 2` are completely equivalent.

The latter type are commands whose name consists of *a single nonletter*.<sup>2</sup>. Spaces after a control symbol are *not* ignored as there's no need to make TeX know where the name ends, because just one character is allowed in the name.

Therefore `\#1` is interpreted as the command (control symbol) `\#` immediately followed by the character 1 and the output will be the expected

> #1

If you type `\# 1` (with a space) you get

> # 1

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> A letter, in this context, is any character of category code 11. With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX the letters are many more.

<sup>2</sup> A nonletter, in this context, is any character of category code different from 11.